# Extracting JSON values and concatenating them using PySpark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a an array of JSONs as below.

```
id  address

1   [{street: 11 Summit Ave, city: null, postal_code: 07306, state: NJ , country: null}, {street: 11 Sum Ave , city: null , postal_code: null, state: NJ, country: US}, {street: 12 Oliver Avenue, city: Seattle , postal_code: 98121, state: WA, country: US}]
```

Here's what the data types are:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- addresses: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- street: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- postalCode: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to create a string of the addresses ignoring nulls and separated by a delimiter (say ;). So output should look like:

```
id  addresses

1   11 Summit Ave 07306 NJ ; 11 Sum Ave NJ US; 12 Oliver Avenue Seattle 98121 WA US
```

How can I achieve this in PySpark? If it matters, my original address is of string type but using from_json, I converted it to the schema specified above.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
df.withColumn("allAdd", F.explode("addresses"))\
.withColumn("asString", F.expr("concat_ws(' ', allAdd.*)"))\
.groupBy("id")\
.agg(F.concat_ws("; ", F.collect_list("asString")).alias("asString"))\
.show(truncate=False)
```

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]